# Что дает наличие transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1) в body

Tags: css

Не первый раз встречаю правило `transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1)`, какое применяется к тегу `<body>`.

Вопрос, что дает данное правило?

Так как у меня от него следующий проблемы: `border` не всегда прорисовывается в таблице и иногда изображения не прогружаются (случай в Google Chrome).
Но! Когда отключаешь это правило, сайт сдвигается(пока еще не понял почему, ведь значения стандартные ИМХО).
На сайтах где-то прочитал, что это для того, чтобы мерцания не было ( но может я не правильно понял). Спасибо

Comment: похоже на хук для рендеринга текста, типа `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`, еще `translate3d(0,0,0)` пишут

Comment: чтобы задействовать GPU и снизить нагрузку с CPU
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176746/css-keyframe-animation-cpu-usage-is-high-should-it-be-this-way/41797773

Comment: чтобы задействовать GPU и снизить нагрузку с CPU
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176746/css-keyframe-animation-cpu-usage-is-high-should-it-be-this-way/41797773

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без [минимального, самодостаточного и воспроизводимого примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) вашей конкретной ошибки сложно сказать наверняка.

Обычно `translateZ(0)` прописывают для того, чтобы отрисовать элементы в GPU еще до того, как анимация началась, чтобы анимация была плавной, без дерганий. `tranform` не перерисовывает объект, он работают напрямую с GPU памятью, которая использует аппаратное ускорение.

`scale(1, 1)` увеличивает содержимое блока в 110% от нормы. Скорее всего именно поэтому вы не видите некоторые бордеры, границы содержимого. Ведь они больше ширины блока на 10% и скорее всего просто в него не влезли. Можете попробовать прописать принудительно `overflow`. Возможно у вас что-то наподобие вот этого:

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.1);
}

.one {
  overflow: hidden
}

.two {
  overflow:auto
}

.three {
  overflow: visible;
}

span {
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class=one><span>1</span></div>
<div class=two><span>2</span></div>
<div class=three><span>3</span></div>
```

Comment: kizoso, а что дает ему, если он пропишет backface-visibility?

Comment: @Air, да что-то не то, исправила

Comment: @kizoso, у меня `scale(1, 1)`, там запятая =)